# Python List Operations: Get Values at Indicies of Unique Elements in a List

Tags: python, numpy

I am newbie in python getting my hands dirty with self defined problem statements and achieving them with simple codes snippets. The problem definition i am trying to solve is : If i have a list of repeating elements i would like to group them based on their values, retrieve their indices at which they occur in the list and get the values from the list.

I tried the sample code below.

```
    import itertools
    import numpy as np
    lst = range(1,5)
    input_list= list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 3) for x in lst))
    print("Input list is {}".format(input_list))
    unique_array = np.unique(np.array(input_list))
    print("Unique Values in the Input List is {}".format(unique_array))
    for i in unique_array:
    for result in np.where(input_list==i):
    print("The Group is {} and it is found at indices {}".format(i, result))
    for j in range(len(result)):
    print("The values of group {} found at indices {} are {}".format(i,result,input_list[j]))
```

Comment: can you provide an example of an input and your expected output?

Comment: So you want to get the values that are unique?

Comment: No, i already have the unique values in - unique_array

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np


lst = range(1,5)
input_list= list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 3) for x in lst))
print("Input list is {}".format(input_list))
unique_array = np.unique(np.array(input_list))
print("Unique Values in the Input List is {}".format(unique_array))
for group_num, uniq_arr in enumerate(unique_array):
    result = np.where(input_list==unique_array[group_num])[0]
    for results in result:
        print("The Group is {} and it is found at indices {}".format(uniq_arr, result))
    for results in result:
        print("The values of group {} found at indices {} are {}".format(input_list[uniq_arr],result,uniq_arr))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am looking for 
The values of group 1 found at indices [0 1 2] are 1                                                                                                                                                                                        2nd,3rd  Line repeats                                                                                                                                          The values of group 2 found at indices [3,4,5] are 2(which is the value of position 3 in the list)

Comment: print("The values of group {} found at indices {} are {}".format(uniq_arr,result,uniq_arr)) - The final parameter directly puts the uniq_arr - i want to use something like "input_array[uniq_arr]" instead of directly giving the name of the unique value